# How do i let token and refresh token in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create 2 token for authentication. I have the tokens. I would like to have expire them on a certain period. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

could you please introduce more details about your problem? (some code may be helpful).

and for this requirement:

> I would like to have expire them on a certain period.

I think we usually implement `expire an token` in `back-end service`:

- step1:generatte one `token`,and save in `redis` or other data service.(Redis has expiration settings for key)
- step2:client send a request to server with this `token`,and the server verify the validity of the `token`.

so it is nothing to do with `Vue`